# impossible for struct to meaningfully store reference with longer lifetime than the containing struct?

Tags: rust

I'd like to have a short-lived struct that contains a reference to longer-lived data (as well as potentially other metadata, omitted in this example). While the short-lived struct is intact, I'd like to be able to extract my longer-lived reference, but I can't get rustc to accept my code. Is this fundamentally impossible? If so, why?

playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7812a30e6beffac05ca3b8e5665987c5

```
struct Foo{}

struct HasRef<'a>(&'a mut Foo);

impl<'a> HasRef<'a> {
    fn get_ref(&mut self) -> &'a mut Foo {
        self.0
    }
    
    fn alt_get_ref<'b>(&'b mut self) -> &'a mut Foo 
    where 'a: 'b
    {
        self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Foo {};
    let mut h = HasRef(&mut f);
    h.get_ref();
}
```

The error message is

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:7:9
  |
5 | impl<'a> HasRef<'a> {
  |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
6 |     fn get_ref(&mut self) -> &'a mut Foo {
  |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
7 |         self.0
  |         ^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`

error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
5  | impl<'a> HasRef<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
10 |     fn alt_get_ref<'b>(&'b mut self) -> &'a mut Foo 
   |                    -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
13 |         self.0
   |         ^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'b`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'b: 'a`

error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: It's fundamentally impossible because it is [unsound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=40c2c20bc83373f5c2422f757febac45).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to return the long lived reference, but as Chaiym Friedman and Ry- pointed out it's *not* possible to return the long lived *exclusive* reference *and still keep it*. It's fine to remove the reference from the struct and then return it for example with `Option`:

```rust
struct HasRef<'a>(Option<&'a mut Foo>);

impl<'a> HasRef<'a> {
    fn get_ref(&mut self) -> &'a mut Foo {
        self.0.take().unwrap()
    }
}
```

The problem also only arises because you're working with mutable, or making the problem more obvious *exclusive* references. It's perfectly fine for `HasRef` to store and return shared references with a lifetime longer than itself even multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Your `alt_get_ref` is pretty close, but you need to return a `&'b mut Foo` so the returned reference can’t be used beyond what the mutable borrow of the `HasRef` can enforce.

```
impl<'a> HasRef<'a> {
    fn get_ref<'b>(&'b mut self) -> &'b mut Foo
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        self.0
    }
}
```

You can’t get a long-lived reference this way for the reason that @ChayimFriedman demonstrated, though. You would have to move it out instead (`fn into_ref(self) -> &'a mut Foo`).

Comment: IMO, this is not what was asked in the question.

Comment: @jthulhu: I also referenced why the other interpretation of what was asked in the question doesn’t work and covered an equivalent of the other answer (`HasRef(Option)` ~= `Option<HasRef>`), so I’m not sure what more you want here.

Comment: The original question was shown unsatisfiable as is. Yet, it is possible to provide the same interface, at the cost of modifying the inner representation of the `HasRef` type. Your interface is *not* the same as the one asked by the OP, and in fact it is impossible to retrieve a borrow that lives longer than the wrapper with your answer.

Comment: @jthulhu: Yeah, which is what I said in the answer.